# How to assign specific dbs value to multiple variables without using multiple query statements?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently creating an Admin Panel and I'm coding it to be 100% fool proof. You'll be able to edit every piece of information through editing phrases from the database.

The main way I know is to use this:

```
$c = $conn->query('SELECT phrase FROM phrases WHERE phrase_name = "corp_name"') or trigger_error($conn->error);

$d = $c->fetch_array();

$phrase_corp_name = $d['phrase']; // "Corporation"
```

This is not very ideal when I'm going to have dozens of phrases.

The issue is, when I try to select a phrase like so, it does nothing:

```
 $phrase_corp_name = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT phrase FROM phrases WHERE phrase_name = 'corp_name'");
```

This should ideally output, "Corporation," which is the value of "phrase" in this instance. I'm assuming the code is wrong, but I can't wrap my head around it.

The error I get here is:

> Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in ... on line 94

Comment: You always have to use `fetch` to retrieve the values that were selected. You can't just print the result of `$conn->query()`, it's an intermediate object.

Comment: What does it output at the moment?

Comment: What does that have to do with your question about fetching dozens of phrases?

Comment: @Barmar Isn't mysqli_query separate from conn-query()? If not, how would I utilize $d to select single values and not just a column?

Comment: No, `mysqli_query` and `$conn->query` are just two different ways of writing the same thing. mysqli allows you to use both procedural and OO syntax, but they're completely interchangeable.

Comment: Ok, before the comment section becomes a train wreck,  could you please explain what is in `phrases`, how do you want to use the values from there, what is the current behaviour of your script and why is it not what you want.

Comment: If you want to look up multiple phrases, you can use `WHERE phrase_name IN ('phrase1', 'phrase2', 'phrase3')`. Then you can fetch the results in a loop to get all the results.

Comment: You have to write `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($phrase_corp_name); echo $row['phrase'];`

Comment: @Dharman The phrases.php file will simply contain a list of variables with the assignment of their database value counterpart. I will then use this file as an include on most pages and reference them via their variable name. I want to do this using the least code possible.

Comment: @Barmar How would that code look if you were assigning it to a variable, without echo. You'll use the variable's assignment to echo it out.

Comment: `$variable = $row['phrase']; echo $variable;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single variable for a single row in the database is completely unnecessary. You can use associative arrays for this purpose; they are perfect for such task.

Get all the results from your `phrases` table into an array and then access the `phrases` using keys.

```
$c = $conn->query('SELECT phrase_name, phrase FROM phrases') or trigger_error($conn->error);
$phrases = [];
foreach ($c as $row) {
    $phrases[$row['phrase_name']] = $row['phrase'];
}
```

and then access the values like this:

```
echo $phrases['corp_name'];
```

As a side note, you would be better off enabling mysqli error reporting, rather than doing it manually yourself. Please read [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)